# Unable to connect to wifi on new arch installation

Tags: arch-linux, wifi

So I recently installed arch linux on a brand new computer. I used a wired connection but now I would like to switch to wifi. However I have not been able to get it to connect (although networks do show).

```
$ ip link
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
3: wlp2s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
link/ether f6:1e:11:6f:fb:bb brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: enp0s20f0u2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
link/ether 70:88:6b:81:1b:de brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff


$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A2 

02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:003e] (rev 32)
Subsystem: Bigfoot Networks, Inc. QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [1a56:1535]
Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
Kernel modules: ath10k_pci

$ iwconfig wlp2s0
wlp2s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
      Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=24 dBm   
      Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Power Management:on

$ cat /etc/wpa_supplicant

ctrl_interface=/var/run/wpa_supplicant
ctrl_interface_group=wheel
network={
    ssid="network"
    psk="password"
}

$ dmesg | grep ath10k
[    2.015433] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    2.016534] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: pci irq msi oper_irq_mode 2     irq_mode 0 reset_mode 0
[    2.275427] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/pre-cal-pci-0000:02:00.0.bin failed with error -2
[    2.275444] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/cal-pci-0000:02:00.0.bin failed with error -2
[    2.276892] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: qca6174 hw3.2 target 0x05030000 chip_id 0x00340aff sub 1a56:1535
[    2.276895] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: kconfig debug 0 debugfs 1 tracing 0 dfs 0 testmode 0
[    2.278075] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: firmware ver WLAN.RM.4.4.1-00051-QCARMSWP-1 api 6 features wowlan,ignore-otp crc32 c3fd4411
[    2.342633] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: board_file api 2 bmi_id N/A crc32 0e26ef70
[    2.928779] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: Unknown eventid: 118809
[    2.931450] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: Unknown eventid: 90118
[    2.932101] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: htt-ver 3.44 wmi-op 4 htt-op 3 cal otp max-sta 32 raw 0 hwcrypto 1
[    3.012656] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0 wlp2s0: renamed from wlan0
[    4.567797] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: Unknown eventid: 118809
[    4.570707] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: Unknown eventid: 90118
[    5.421254] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: Unknown eventid: 118809
[    5.424174] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: Unknown eventid: 90118
```

Not sure what to do. Tried wifi-menu, iw, netctl and networkmanager. Unable to connect no matter what I try. Access points show though. The network I'm attempting to connect to is found.

Comment: Connect manually; it will provide more detailed debugging messages when it fails.

Comment: Try `lspci -k` to check if the driver for your PCI-card has been loaded.

Check kernel messages for firmware being loaded: `dmesg | grep firmware`

Also run `rfkill list` to see if your wlan is blocked (either soft or hard). If softblocked use `rfkill unblock wifi`.

Answer (score -1):

when you run NetworkManager, then you can configure your WLAN with it and then have a log at /var/log/syslog or /var/log/messages and see what NetworkManager is doing and where it's failing.